# wlan0 is not permanently turned down by ifconfig

Tags: wireless, ifconfig

I am trying to turn off my wifi interface using the following ifconfig command:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

My wifi disconnected for almost one second and then it comes back up again.

what is the problem and how I fix it ?

Comment: use `rfkill` instead? most likely networkmanager overrides your manual config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably use network-manager, try `nmcli nm wifi off`.